# Product of 2 bounded sequences is a bounded sequence

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

If sequences $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ are bounded then the sequence $(a_n*b_n)$ is bounded

Let $(a_n)$=$f(x)$ and $(b_n)$= $g(x)$ Then if

$f$ is bounded means that $|f(x)| \leq C$ for all $x$. Similarly $|g(x)| \leq D$ for all $x$. Therefore the triangle inequality gives $|f(x) g(x)| \leq |f(x)| |g(x)| \leq C . D$ for all $x$ and hence $fg$ is bounded by $C D$.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: Are you trying to verify you solution? Because I don't see a question here.

Comment: yes, just edited the question

Comment: Apart from that not being the triangle inequality and using $x$ instead of $n$, it looks good to me.

Answer (score 1):

- The triangle inequality is not $|ab|\leq |a||b|$, but $|a+b|\leq |a|+|b|$
- The sequence $a_n$ is a function of $x \in \mathbb{N}$, so I think it is clearer to write $(a_n)_n=:f$, and then $a_n=f(n)$
- The proof is correct

Comment: There's no need to introduce $f$ and $g$ at all, the sequences already have names. We have $|a_n|\le C$ and $|b_n|\le D$ so $|a_n b_n| = |a_n|\, |b_n| \le C\, D$.

Comment: Right, I should have started my second point with 'if you really want to rename the sequences'

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is ok.
I would like to give a definition may be it will help for similar problems.

**Definition**: Let $X$ be a nonempty set. A sequence in $X$ is a function
$f : \Bbb{N}\to X$. We let $a_n := f(n)$ and call $a_n$ the $n^{th}$ term of the sequence. One
usually denotes $f$ by $(a_n)$ or as an infinite tuple $(a_1, a_2, . . . , a_n, . . .)$.